# What are the 360 degree cameras compatible with ROS?

Tags: ros, laserscanner, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to know what are the 360 degree cameras compatible with ROS platform?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278172/what-are-the-360-degree-cameras-compatible-with-ros?/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2017-12-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've been using the Ricoh Theta S successfully, using the [gscam driver](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam). It's a bit tedious to use as it has to be switched into "webcam" mode using buttons on the camera everytime it is used however. Also, right now, it appears one is limited to 720P images containing both fisheye images side by side via mjpg. The camera itself can do 1080P/H264, but this still doesn't work with current Linux Kernels AFAIK.

What I'd really be interested in is a nice 360 deg camera with a USB3.0 interface, but it seems the focus for consumer cams is on WiFi unfortunately.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-12-27**:
For example, I used a normal monochrome camera to do feature learning with deep learning. Can I use it for ricoh theta camera without making any changes? That's why I asked that question. All-round cameras do not give a flat image. They give a global image.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2017-12-28**:
You'll have to perform some sort of calibration and projection of the fisheye image for things to work. The kalibr calibration toolbox is a very starting point for that.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-01-04**:
thank you very much Mr. Kohlbrecher